# Empty content picker does not return null when empty

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content picker for a custom content type that needs to be placed in a specific zone on the page. It is working just fine with code like this (in Orchard 1.9.1):

In placement.info:

```
  <Match ContentType="MyContentType">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
      <Place Fields_ContentPicker-MyFieldName="MyZoneName:1"/>
    </Match>
  </Match>
```

In the shape file (such as Content-MyContentType.Detail.cshtml):

```
@if (Model.MyZoneName != null)
{
    <div class="my-class">
        <h3>Some Title</h3>
        @Zone(Model.MyZoneName)
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that if I have a content item with no content items in the content picker, it still displays "Some Title" because for some reason Model.MyZoneName is not coming back as null.

I have tried countless things including these to no avail:

- `@if (Model.ContentItem.MyPartName.MyFieldName.Count > 1)` but there doesn't seem to be any available values that return the number of content items;
- `@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MyZoneName))` and `@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ContentItem.MyPartName.MyFieldName.items[0]))` and others like that returned various error messages.
- etc.

How can I get my check to return empty if there are no content items? It would be best if it was done with fix to the content picker module (assuming that's the issue), instead of trying to hack through .

Comment: It displays the zone because there indeed is a field placed in that zone. The field however doesn't have any 'items picked', but the zone does not know that. It only knows that it does have a field, and therefore displays the zone

Comment: Thanks @devqon. That helps and validates what I'm seeing, but doesn't really address the issue. The answer in many cases is to put the markup in the shape file for the content picker, but my case is more complex than the example and requires the surrounding markup.

Comment: What @devqon is explaining is that you're doing this in the wrong place. You template override for Content doesn't have access to your field's shape, only to the zones. In your code, you are just testing if MyZoneName exists, which it does. It's in the template for the field, not in the template for Content, that you should be doing the test.